# How to delete Personal Certificate

Tags: windows, powershell

I am planning to delete a personal certificate based on Issuer and Certificate Template.
So far, I have already the script to delete based on Issuer, but I have no idea on how to delete based on both Issuer and Certificate Template. Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Script to Delete from Issuer:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My |
Where{$_.Issuer -match 'XXX'} | 
Remove-Item
```

Comment: You can have multiple conditions like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3#example-6-use-multiple-conditions).

Comment: Hi I tried to run the script like this but seems like the script can run but when i check back the certificate is still there.
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My |
Where{$_.Issuer -match 'MY-SUBCA-CA'} and { $_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "Certificate Template Information" } |
Remove-Item

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, have a closer look to the linked example.

Comment: Appologies i send the wrong one the correct version should be like this but even the corrected one I still getting the same issue which the script runned but not remove
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My |
Where-Object { $_.Issuer -match "XXX" -and $_.Oid.FriendlyName -eq "XXX" } |
Remove-Item